# Ошибка: AttributeError при импорте функции из другого файла

Tags: python, python-3.x, импорт, модули

У меня есть два файла **tttt.py** и **gg.py**. Я импортирую функцию из **tttt.py** и у меня возникает ошибка:

> print(tttt.ga('hi'))
> ^^^^^^^
> AttributeError: module 'tttt' has no attribute 'ga'

**gg.py**:

```
import tttt

print(tttt.ga('hi'))
print('hi')
```

**tttt.py**:

```
def ga(f):
    return f
```

Как ее исправить?

[image: ошибка]

Comment: Скопировал ваш код в два файла, запустил, ошибок нет. Возможно проблема в IDE, у меня нет VS Code, попробуйте закрыть - открыть VS Code

Comment: Может нет автосейва файлов и на момент запуска в tttt не было сохранено изменение

Comment: проблема была в vs code, я открыл этот же файл  в vs и все заработало

Comment: @dratyti Это не VSCode, это что-то не настроено. Можно попробовать в настройках установить `"terminal.integrated.env.windows": { "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}" }`

Comment: @Alexander Lonberg куда это вводить в настройках, я просто не разбираюсь, пошаговый план пожалуйста если не трудно

Comment: @dratyti С Python трудно описать пошаговый план, обычно план реализуется чтением документации и методом проб и ошибок. Этот план и установка расширений описаны в документации [VSCode python](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/python). Настройки это локальный для проекта файл `.vscode/settings.json` или [глобальный для пользователя](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings). Так же в настройках можно прописать `"python.envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env"` и добавить в каталог проекта файл `.env` с одной строкой `PYTHONPATH=.`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Хотя у меня ошибок нет, но предложу попробовать так:

**gg.py**:

```
#import tttt
from tttt import ga

#print(tttt.ga('hi'))
print(ga('hi'))

print(f"gg.py: {'hi'}")
```

**tttt.py**:

```
def ga(f):
    return 'def ga(f): ' + f
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: так уже пробовали https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCQx7.png