# Проблема импорта модуля из директории

Tags: python, импорт, fastapi

Такая ошибка
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал и `__init__.py` - не работает. Пробовал и подобное `import db.crud as crud` - не работает.

Вот структура проекта.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот сам круд модуль.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вызываю все через `uvicorn app.main:app --reload`.
Помогите, пожалуйста, либо я чего-то не знаю, либо не вижу в упор проблему. Если нужно будет дополнительной информации - напишите, покажу/напишу.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1547139/251478 тут человек пробовал, пришли к выводу, что может быть проблема с VSCode, но это не точно, у меня нет VSCode проверить не могу, но я создал каталог d/, важно в том же каталоге откуда запускается main.py, там еще каталог dt/ и файл f.py, там def f() `import d.dt.f
d.dt.f.f()` проверил все работает.

Comment: `from app.db import crud` может быть?

Comment: Я у себя проверил `from d.dt.f import f
f()` так тоже работает.

Comment: Спасибо, @Oopss, я надеялся сделать более красиво, конечно...) Но так как вы описали работает

Comment: @Konstantin более красиво, это как, подробней можно?

Comment: Пришлось еще несколько импортов менять, правильный вариант `from app.db.crud import foo`, к сожалению, как сделать красивее - не знаю

Comment: @Oopss, ну, вот как я писал в проблеме `from db import crud`, так лаконично выглядит, думаю, что я либо модули как-то плохо расположил, либо не понимаю работу импортов)

Comment: Так тоже должно работать, только вызывать нужно crud.foo()

Comment: @strawdog, странно, когда я пробовал так - не работало, короче шумихи навел, `from app.db import crud` - тоже работает. Может кто-нибудь объяснить, почему нужно именно с `app` начинать, ведь app рабочая же часть, или нет?

Comment: @Oopss, к сожалению, именно так и не работает. Поэтому вопрос-то и создал))